# How do i call the parsed data from the GET request that have a longer nested JSON structure in Swift?

Tags: ios, json, swift, swiftui, decode

NOTE: Forgive my cluelessness, i am still new in regards to this. The full code is posted at the bottom.

ISSUE: It seems that when i have a short nest, i am able to call it for my @Published property however when i try an api request with a longer nest, [like this.](http://xmlopen.rejseplanen.dk/bin/rest.exe/trip?originId=8600790&destId=6553&format=json) and type Decodable structs that follows the structure of the GET request

```
struct TripScheduleTest: Codable {
    let TripList: InitialNest
}
struct InitialNest: Codable {
    var Trip: [TravelDetail]

}
struct TravelDetail: Codable {
    var Leg: [TripTest]
}
struct TripTest: Codable, Hashable {
    var name: String
    var type: String
}
```

I am not able to call it for the `@Published var dataSet1 = [TripTest]()`

```
                self.dataSet1 = tripJSON.TripList.Trip.Leg
```

[I get an error message, that says "Value of type '[TravelDetail]' has no member 'Leg'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kzQN.png)

I am not sure why, however it works when i use `[TravelDetail]()` instead of `[TripTest]()` in the @Published var and stop at Trip before Leg for the dataSet1, then it seems to at least build successfully. But now i am not able to get the name and type information from the request

Full code

```
import SwiftUI

struct TripScheduleTest: Codable {
    let TripList: InitialNest
}
struct InitialNest: Codable {
    var Trip: [TravelDetail]

}
struct TravelDetail: Codable {
    var Leg: [TripTest]
}
struct TripTest: Codable, Hashable {
    var name: String
    var type: String
}



class TripViewModel: ObservableObject {

    @Published var dataSet1 = [TripTest]()

    init() {
        let urlString = "http://xmlopen.rejseplanen.dk/bin/rest.exe/trip?originId=8600790&destId=6553&format=json"
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return }
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, resp, err) in

            guard let data = data else { return }
            do {
                let tripJSON = try
                    JSONDecoder().decode(TripScheduleTest.self, from: data)
                print(data)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.dataSet1 = tripJSON.TripList.Trip.Leg
                }





            } catch {
                print("JSON Decode error: ", error)
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}


struct TripView: View {

@ObservedObject var vm = TripViewModel()

var body: some View {


    List(vm.dataSet1, id: \.self) { day in
        Text("Test")
            .font(.system(size: 12, weight: .bold))
        Text(" \(day.name)")
            .font(.system(size: 12))
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Trip` is an array (note the `[]`)

You need to get one item of the array by index for example

```
tripJSON.TripList.Trip.first?.Leg
```

To assign the value to a non-optional array write

```
self.dataSet1 = tripJSON.TripList.Trip.first?.Leg ?? []
```

Comment: Gotcha. the fact that it was declared as [TravelDetail] was a mistake. It was an old troubleshooting that i forgot to change back to [TripTest]. However when i add the `.first?` it seems to create an red error and suggest a fix like `self.dataSet1 = tripJSON.TripList.Trip.first?.Leg as! [TripTest]` Which it then becomes a yellow warning. But it does work now at least.

Comment: If `dataSet1` is declared as `[TripTest]` you have to assign `self.dataSet1 = tripJSON.TripList.Trip.first?.Leg ?? []`. But be aware that even there are multiple trips only the first trip is considered.